# How to modify SharePoint embed results using the /_layouts/15/embed.aspx endpoint?

Tags: sharepoint, embed

Lets say I have a document:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site-collection}/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx
```

Then I can use the "endpoint"  `_layouts/15/embed.aspx?Id=` for an url that I can use to embed that document:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site-collection}/_layouts/15/embed.aspx?Id=/sites/{site-collection}/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx
```

How can I modify that url to **hide the border and the page control**?

Where can I find a documentation on the supported query arguments?

Is it possible to use this api endpoint to modify the resulting view? For example hide the border and the page navigation?

I asked some AI chat about the query options and it suggested some options. However, none of them seems to work except the Id.

- `Id`: Specifies the document ID or URL of the document to be embedded. (Required)

**Related**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-a-sharepoint-space-with-the-embed-web-part-7ffe2898-edcf-4556-88b8-16567fc2ab7a

https://sharepointstuff.com/2021/03/30/useful-sharepoint-urls/comment-page-1/

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: @Stefan any idea where the person got that list from? I'm also trying to find a list of valid parameters to pass to `embed.aspx` but couldn't find anything in the official documentation beyond the default `?UniqueId=...` that you get when you manually Embed a document.

Comment: The previously shown list has been hallucinated by AI. I wanted to mention what I already tried and failed. I just shortened the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find extra query options and the result of embed endpoint contains a nested iframe structure where content is loaded in several steps.

Thefore, I applied following css workaround to hide the pagination control and "zoom in" to hide the borders for embedded Word documents:

```
div .ItemPreview-detailsBar {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
}

#WebApplicationFrame {  
  margin-left:-15px;
  margin-top:-15px;  
  width: 108%; 
  height: 108%;   
  background-color: white !important; 
}
```